# How to know what record(s) was updated, deleted, or inserted in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm doing a LogTable, where I save the data that was modified on the RealTable.

By data I mean that I need to recover the whole record's `:new` and `:old` values. So I have a trigger that reacts whether there's an insert, delete or update.

So my question is: How do I know which record was changed and how do I recover it's contents?

example:

```
create table t1(
    a integer,
    b integer
)

create table LogT1(
    new_a integer, 
    old_a integer,
    new_b integer,
    old_b integer
)
```

Let's say there's a record on t1 with the values a=1, b=2 and t1 gets an update so the record changes the values to a=3, b=4

So that update activates the trigger and it must:

1. Know which record was modified.
2. Recover that record.
3. Get the "before" and "after" an and b values
4. Insert those values into LogT1 as old_a, new_a, old_b, new_b

resulting as an insert on LogT1 with the values  new_a=3, old_a=1, new_b=4, old_b=2

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER tr001
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON t1

DECLARE

    a integer;
    b integer;
    a2 integer;
    b2 integer;

BEGIN

    IF DELETING THEN 

        *Recover the row that changed* 

        *Then use that row*
        a2:= :new.a ;
        b2:= :new.b ;
        a:= :old.a ;
        b:= :old.b ;
        insert into LogT1 (new_a integer, old_a integer, new_b integer, old_b integer) 
values (a2,a,b2,b);

    END IF;

....

END tr001;
```

---

I'm new at this so my most sincere apology if my question is not proper.

Comment: I am not sure about the complete solution.But i am sure that writing triggers for the table might help you!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember you might declare the trigger as `FOR EACH ROW` so that it is fired for each row that is deleted|inserted|updated, then the :new and :old contain the specific row values. Hope this helps.

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER tr001 
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
  ON t1
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 11g, you can use [Flashback Data Archive](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17125/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011) to do this,

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can recover the old data, if you know the time at which the data required, without creating the log table using following query. It may satisfy your requirement.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME AS OF TIMESTAMP
```

(Provide the time at which time the records required as the timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

This is some PL/SQL I use in a project to do pretty much the exact thing you want.

I've simplified my script (it was doing some other functionality):

```
create or replace trigger rtt.course_log
       after insert or update or delete
       on rtt.TRAINING_COURSE
       for each row

declare msg varchar2(255);

begin
        if updating then
           msg := 'updating course: ' ||  :new.name || 'at: ' || :new.updated_at;
        elsif inserting then
           msg := 'creating course: ' ||  :new.name || 'at: ' || :new.updated_at;
        elsif deleting then
           msg := 'deleting course: ' ||  :new.name || 'at: ' || :new.updated_at;
        end if;
        insert into rtt.TRAINING_LOG (message, created_at) values (msg, SYSDATE);
end;
```